# IndexedDB - Prevent indexeddb.sqlite3-wal file from growing to GBs

Tags: logging, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

In my PWA, I use a combination of SQLjs and IndexedDB for persistence. I am running into a problem with the indexeddb.sqlite3-wal file to where the file is growing so large it is triggering safari to increase space to 1.2GB and more. I have to tried to delete the indexedDB before every write to remove (reset) the file, but that creates race conditions therefore causing my program to block. Is there another way to reset or remove the log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all who come across this, this was an issue with Safari and so the developers at Webkit have made a fix for the issue and I believe it will ship with the IOS 14 release (Current IOS at the time is 13.7). If you have the latest safari technology preview, the fix is located there.